# XML Switching Order Of Attributes

Tags: xml

I  am new to xml and am having some trouble understanding the behavior of it when viewing it in a  browser. My XML structure looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<GamesSuites>


<Suites>


<Suite Name="Favorites" ID="Favorites">


<Games>

<Game Name="Lucky 7" ID="2" ImagePath="#images/Provider_11_1/Games/casinoGames_01.jpg"/>

<Game Name="Diamond Jackpot" ID="32" ImagePath="#images/Provider_11_1/Games/casinoGames_02.jpg"/>

<Game Name="Royal Reels" ID="223" ImagePath="#images/Provider_11_1/Games/casinoGames_03.jpg"/>

<Game Name="Safari Sam" ID="280" ImagePath="#images/Provider_11_1/Games/casinoGames_04.jpg"/>

<Game Name="Treasure Room" ID="158" ImagePath="#images/Provider_11_1/Games/casinoGames_05.jpg"/>

<Game Name="Aztec Treasures" ID="190" ImagePath="#images/Provider_11_1/Games/casinoGames_06.jpg"/>

</Games>

</Suite>

</Suites>

</GamesSuites>
```

When viewed in  a browser  though the Name  and  ID attributes are swapped  around. 
So in the browser when viewing it it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<GamesSuites>


<Suites>


<Suite Name="Favorites" ID="Favorites">


<Games>

<Game ID="2" Name="Lucky 7"  ImagePath="#images/Provider_11_1/Games/casinoGames_01.jpg"/>

<Game ID="32" Name="Diamond Jackpot"  ImagePath="#images/Provider_11_1/Games/casinoGames_02.jpg"/>

<Game ID="223" Name="Royal Reels"  ImagePath="#images/Provider_11_1/Games/casinoGames_03.jpg"/>

<Game ID="280" Name="Safari Sam"  ImagePath="#images/Provider_11_1/Games/casinoGames_04.jpg"/>

<Game ID="158" Name="Treasure Room"  ImagePath="#images/Provider_11_1/Games/casinoGames_05.jpg"/>

<Game ID="190" Name="Aztec Treasures" ImagePath="#images/Provider_11_1/Games/casinoGames_06.jpg"/>

</Games>

</Suite>

</Suites>

</GamesSuites>
```

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Because browser interprets your XML code and tries to output it in some constant order. It's not error or something.

Comment: It doesn't matter how browser is displaying the XML. Whenever you want to manipulate the XML you will always use the attribute name("name" or "Id"..etc) to get the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, the attributes of an XML element are an *unordered* set of key/value pairs.  An XML parser is not required to preserve the order in which attributes were given in the source, and an XML-consuming application won't care what that order was.